# Flutter: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider androidx.startup.InitializationProvider

Tags: android, admob, flutter-dependencies, google-mobile-ads

I'm trying to show native ads (rest of ads are working fine) from this package:
https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads

These are the 3 files modified:

- MainActivity.java
- NativeAdFactoryExample.java
- my_native_ad.xml

but got this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(16282): Process: com.drodriguez.my_rents, PID: 16282
E/AndroidRuntime(16282): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider androidx.startup.InitializationProvider: androidx.startup.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WorkManager is already initialized.  Did you try to initialize it manually without disabling WorkManagerInitializer? See WorkManager#initialize(Context, Configuration) or the class level Javadoc for more information.
E/AndroidRuntime(16282):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6988)
```

---

For this issue I tried this fix: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/app-startup, but got a different error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig' property 'buildConfigPackageName'.
   > Failed to query the value of property 'packageName'.
      > org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/Users/dani/repos/dani/my_rents/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml; lineNumber: 71; columnNumber: 35; The prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:node" associated with an element type "provider" is not bound.
```

Flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on macOS 11.6.1 20G224 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.62.0)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: There is an issue created for this, take a look : https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/issues/450

Comment: yes, it's me. I got rid of this issue by creating a new project